# Haskell list comprehension returns empty?

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

So I'm new to learning Haskell (started on Saturday) and I read a few chapters from online books and I wrote a list comprehension to find the diameter of a circle given its circumference.

`ghci> let circle = [(a) | a <- [1..10], 9 / pi == a]` but it returns `[]` I was told this is because `[1..10]` only counts whole integers and not all the real numbers between 1 and 10.

I tried  `ghci> let circle = [(a) | a <- [1..10], round (pi * a) == 9]` which returns `[3.0]` but I was wondering if there was a way to get a more precise answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be happy that it doesn't count all real numbers between 1 and 10. It would be just too boring to watch that program run for eternities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to Haskell and StackOverflow!

> `let circle = [(a) | a <- [1..10], 9 / pi == a]`

Considering all the real numbers between 1 and 10 is an [uncountably infinite set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument) (hat tip to Georg Cantor for that one) I'd be surprised, to say the least, if you managed to make a list comprehension over them. :)

Your reasoning about why this list is empty is correct -- `9/pi` will never equal a whole integer.

Other than that, there's no reason to use a list comprehension for this. You can do the same thing by simply dividing by pi:

```
let diam c = c / pi
```

Comment: Had to give you the +1 for the reference to Cantor.

Comment: Shout-out to my homies at the _Deutsche Mathematiker-Vereinigung_.

Comment: (no, but seriously, if you haven't seen Cantor's diagonal proof, read [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument); it's one of the simplest and most beautiful proofs in math in my opinion)

Comment: Having proved that the reals were uncountably infinite, he then noted that the algebraic numbers were countable, and therefore transcendental numbers must exist -- even though no known number had been proved to be transcendental at the time.  According to one of my maths teachers, he got into terrible trouble for that inference, and became ostracised by the community.

Comment: @ChristianTernus I think the simplicity of the proof is a bit deceptive. For example, if you believe that 0.011111... = 0.1, then simply "having different digits in some position" does not make two numbers distinct. Patching this up is harder than you might guess at first; even the comments in the section "Real numbers" of your link doesn't seem to quite get to a full patch.

Comment: That said, once you formalize it, diagonalization as a general proof technique shows up over and over and over whenever someone wants to show that some system is getting too large for its own good.

Answer (score 3):

This is not what list comprehensions are used for.  To get a precise answer to `9 / pi`, just calculate `9 / pi` directly.

```
ghci> let diam = 9/pi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
diameter c = c / pi
```

or as you get more advanced in Haskell:

```
diameter = (/ pi)
```

And then you can call:

```
Prelude> diameter 9
2.864788975654116
```

A list comprehension may be useful if you wanted the diameters of the circles with circumferences from 1 to 10, like so:

```
Prelude> [diameter x | x <- [1..10]]
[0.3183098861837907,0.6366197723675814,0.954929658551372,1.2732395447351628,1.5915494309189535,1.909859317102744,2.228169203286535,2.5464790894703255,2.864788975654116,3.183098861837907]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
let circle = [ 9 / pi ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just find the diameter of a circle with a given circumference?

```
diameterOfCircleWithCircumference :: Floating a => a -> a
diameterOfCircleWithCircumference = (/ pi)
```

Then `diameterOfCircleWithCircumference 9` is 2.8947...